# Angular $scope variables updating on their own

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two variables. But updating 1 causes the other to update too. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

```
$scope.pages = [];
$scope.pagesSave = [];

var functionName = function(){

  $service.doThing1().then(function(res1){
    $scope.pagesSave = res1;
    console.log(res1)
    $service.doThing2().then(function(res2){
      $scope.pages = $service.formatThings(res2, res1);
      console.log($scope.pages)

  }, function(err){});
}, function(err){});
```

$scope.pages should be the final product

$scope.pagesSave should be the pre-formatted data

however, console logging these variables show them as being identical.

More oddly, console logging immediately after doing $service.doThing1() shows "res1" as having the correct length but only containing the data from $scope.pages, as seen in this image.

2 are missing even though the formatting function hasn't happened yet

[image]

Anyone know whats happening here?

I'm using Chrome for console logs if that helps

Comment: Too many unknowns....provide a **runnable** [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that inside your `formatThings` you send `res1` as a result of your function which means `$scope.pagesSave` will equal `res1` which will be equal to `$scope.pages`.

So the solution is to use `angular.copy()` to create a deep copy of your `res1` and use the created object to clean it up. Can you share your `formatThings`?

Comment: Thank you! Tried this and had a look through the docs / examples for angular.copy(). This is what I needed!

Comment: You are welcome. Consider marking the question as answered ;)